# Stellar all address has no data

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk

Hi i was using stellar test account. It was working fine but suddenly showing no data in any related account to a asset issuer. is there any limit for using test network ?

I have created a issuer and a distributor with a custom token.
No data in distributor and issuer account as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe due to yesterday's scheduled cleanup. After clean up all the data's that are stored in the testnetwork will be removed permanently. Anyway the custom asset details will be not shown in issuer account. It can only be visible in the distributor accounts where you transfer the amount from issuer or created the trustline to issuer

Comment: How do we know scheduled cleanup dates? Are they inform somewhere before scheduled cleanup ?

Comment: This was communicated on the slack channel 2-3 weeks ago, and possibly through other channels too. There's a mailing list, e.g.

Comment: Can you send me the link of slack Chanel. I mean how to add myself in stellar slack Chanel ? @JohanStén

Answer (score 1):

The testnet was reset, that's why everything is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Periodic Reset of Testnet Data
In order to preserve a good experience for developers, the SDF testnet is periodically reset to the genesis (initial) ledger. This ensures the removal of spam, minimizing the time to catch up to the latest ledger, and easier maintenance of the system over time.
When this happens, all ledger entries (such as accounts, trustlines, offers, etc), transactions, and historical data are cleared for both Stellar Core and Horizon.
As a result, all the data's that are stored in the testnetwork had removed permanently.